# How can I extend the view into the title bar in a JavaScript/CSS/HTML UPW project?

Tags: javascript, css, uwp

I'm trying to extend the view into the title bar with a UWP project based on JavaScript/CSS/HTML and I can't figure out how to access the correct API's. In the UWP samples from Github I found a reference to a custom helper class that is written in c++, but the reference I'm making to the class in javascript is not working. Here's my project structure

[image]

And here's my javascript

```
(function () {
    setupPanel();
    configTitlebar();
})();

function setupPanel() {
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize = { width: 700, height: 320 };
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.preferredLaunchViewSize;
}

function configTitlebar() {
    var titleBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView().titleBar;
    titleBar.backgroundColor = { a: 0, r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 };
    titleBar.foregroundColor = { a: 255, r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 };
    titleBar.buttonBackgroundColor = { a: 0, r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 };
    titleBar.buttonForegroundColor = { a: 255, r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 };

    var titleBarHelper = CoreViewHelpers.CoreTitleBarHelper.getForCurrentView();
    var extend = extendView.checked;
    titleBarHelper.extendViewIntoTitleBar = extend;
}
```

I'm getting this error when I try and reference CoreViewHelpers

```
Unhandled exception at line 18, column 5 in ms-appx://3146901b-10fb-4c64-95cb-a923fbe5c04e/js/main.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'CoreViewHelpers' is not defined
```

I'm trying to get this information from their (Microsoft's) Github sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar/js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extending the view into the title bar in a JavaScript UWP project, you can [create a Simple Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript). The following is the detailed step.

In your solution, you can create a C# Windows Runtime component,

```
namespace TitleBarHelper
{
    public sealed class CoreTitleBarHelper
    {
        public void ExtendViewIntoTitleBar(bool IsExtend)
        {
            var currentview = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
            currentview.TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = IsExtend;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your WinJS UWP project, you should add the Windows Runtime component project as a reference project. After that, you can call the `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` method to extend the view to the title bar.

```
"use strict";
var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
var isFirstActivation = true;
var helper = new TitleBarHelper.CoreTitleBarHelper();
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand) {
        // TODO
    }
    else if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.arguments) {
            // TODO
        }
        else if (args.detail.previousExecutionState === activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO
        }
        helper.extendViewIntoTitleBar(true);
    }
```

Comment: I added the C# runtime component and added it as a reference to my WinJS project, but when I reference "var helper = new TitleBarHelper.CoreTitleBarHelper();" I get an unknown runtime error. Any ideas? The error description is not helpful at all, it just says it's unknown.

Comment: @MaxMcKinney It is strange and it works well in my side without any error, could you create a repro project and provide the link to help me see the issue?

Comment: I tested my project on a different computer and there were no issues! There must be something corrupt on the system I was using. Thanks for your help!